# vim-latex suite not compiling

Tags: vim-latex

Whenever I try to compile my LaTeX on vim using vim-latex and \ll I get the following error

vDoc.tex
|| I can't find file `0'. 0
|| Emergency stop. 0 
[Quickfix List] :latex -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error-style 0                                  1,1             All

How to fix this? I have the latex version of Mac OS X. Also I have tried to fix by typing in latex -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error-style 0    to no avail.
Please help.

Thanks.

EDIT: When I type in the command 
:!latex -interaction=nonstopmode % it compiles but whenever I do \ll it doesn't
Furthermore when I use :!latex -interaction=nonstopmode % it doesn't go over the errors when I hit enter...Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Also I think vim may believe that there is no output on the file, while there clearly is.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Perhaps you want to ask over here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I recently had what I think was the same error after upgrading vim-LaTeX to the latest version on a vim 7.4 installation. Recent updates seem to use `v:true` and `v:false` which were only introduced in Vim 8. Didn't find a fix in my case, I just reverted to a slightly older version of vim-LaTeX.

Comment: Can you confirm the version of Vim used?  I can't replicate exactly the reported error message but do get the `! I can't find file \`0'.` part and the differences may just be different compilation calls.

Comment: I have since fixed this issue, but I do not remember how...I had vim 7.4 but I have since upgraded to vim 8...

Comment: What do you have in your vimrc for LatexSuite?

Comment: @user279540 I've added an answer as I think this error must be due to vim-LaTeX requiring commands which don't exist in vim 7.4.  My `.vimrc` has a few things in it, I think `filetype plugin on` and `set nocompatible` are the two necessary ones, if you've resolved this error and are still having problems feel free to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a problem with running versions of vim-LaTeX from between January 2018 ([042f247](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/commit/042f2476a69e5e85eb2399788c930e78b8cbc47b#diff-c052f7bc5c768c12220a57b75ff33540)) and November 2018 ([ae0ecab](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/commit/ae0ecabcf9109fa295f2216071f16bb5f0f605ce)) on vim 7.4 or earlier.  As of [this last commit](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/commit/ae0ecabcf9109fa295f2216071f16bb5f0f605ce) vim-LaTeX should work normally on vim 7.4.  If constrained to vim 7.4 or earlier the solution should now be upgrade vim-LaTeX.

---

Using the latest version of vim-LaTeX on vim 7.4 I get

```
1 || I can't find file `0'. 0
2 || Emergency stop.
3 ||  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

which is preceded on my setup by a notice

```
Error detected while processing function Tex_RunLaTeX..Tex_SetupErrorWindow..Tex_GetMainFileName:
line   23:
E121: Undefined variable: v:true
E116: Invalid arguments for function glob('*.latexmain',v:true) == ''
E15: Invalid expression: glob('*.latexmain',v:true) == ''
line   34:
E121: Undefined variable: v:true
E116: Invalid arguments for function glob('*.latexmain',v:true)
E15: Invalid expression: glob('*.latexmain',v:true)
line   35:
E121: Undefined variable: lheadfile
E15: Invalid expression: lheadfile != ''
line   51:
E121: Undefined variable: lheadfile
```

The first complaint of this being about `v:true`, consulting the list of new  features in vim 8 we can see that one of those is the addition of the new [vim variable `v:true`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/52d3aaeea4c85406f46e2051729e4f007f83b35e/runtime/doc/version8.txt#L352).

Since a January 2018 commit ([042f247](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/commit/042f2476a69e5e85eb2399788c930e78b8cbc47b#diff-c052f7bc5c768c12220a57b75ff33540)) vim-LaTeX code relies on the existence of the `v:true` variable.  My solution was simply to revert to the vim-LaTeX source just before the aforementioned commit, using the repository as of [e6972ac](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/tree/e6972ac989b46068e9490626e3ea5d6144c45617), though of course upgrading to vim 8.0 would be the easier fix.

The commit [042f247](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/commit/042f2476a69e5e85eb2399788c930e78b8cbc47b#diff-c052f7bc5c768c12220a57b75ff33540) could selectively be omitted from vim-LaTeX, as of the most recent commit ([dc2053c](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/commit/dc2053cd45caeb4e61d461a7d889cee5d55b67d9)) no additional uses of `v:true` have been made but this could interfere with future updates.  It may also be possible to define `v:true` with vim script but that's beyond me (possibly a question for https://vi.stackexchange.com/).