# After installation vim-latex is not properly working

Tags: installing, vim-latex

I downloaded vim-Latex from https://sourceforge.net/projects/vim-latex/files/, and installed vim-Latex by hand (without Vundle or similar). I followed the instructions on the page: 
http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=download&title=Download

However, upon opening an already existing (la)tex-file with vim I don't get the menu bar as it is shown on the page: http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/screenshots/template-menu.png

So I cannot choose a particular template type. But it is even worse. Upon typing `\ll` at the beginning it did not work at all, but after simplifying my `.vimrc` file it finally worked, however, it spits out a lot of error messages which apparently have nothing to do with my (la)tex-file (in particular because a call of `latex (la)tex-file` at the commandline prompt works perfectly without any error):

```
Error detected while processing function Tex_RunLaTeX..Tex_SetupErrorWindow..Tex_GetMainFileName: 

line   23:
E121: Undefined variable: v:true
E116: Invalid arguments for function glob('*.latexmain',v:true) == ''

E15: Invalid expression: glob('*.latexmain',v:true) == ''
line   34:
E121: Undefined variable: v:true
E116: Invalid arguments for function glob('*.latexmain',v:true)

E15: Invalid expression: glob('*.latexmain',v:true)
line   35:
E121: Undefined variable: lheadfile
E15: Invalid expression: lheadfile != ''
line   51:
E121: Undefined variable: lheadfile
E15: Invalid expression: lheadfile
```

I am using vim 7.4 on a KDE OpenSuse Linux system (version number at least 14). I've never used a vim-plugin, so actually my experience in the field is still limited. But as I use Latex a lot, I thought it would be useful to give vim-Latex a try. Thank you for any help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Have you tried installing the latest version from [github](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex)? I think this is the same problem as [vim-latex suite not compiling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/419515/106162)

Comment: Also are you using Vim or gVim? The latter is necessary for the menu bar I believe, it's not necessary to access the templates though this can be done through keyboard commands.

Comment: I use Vim. Actually I mentioned missing menu bar only to show some symptoms of my installation, I am more concerned by the error messages and the lacking compiler result, the .dvi file. The version I downloaded is "vim-latex-1.10.0.tar.gz" from sourceforge.

Comment: OK then, as I said, it sounds like the question I linked to earlier. For a time, I believe including v1.10, vim-LaTeX required features of Vim 8, this dependency was recently removed and the latest commit to the github master should be fine. Any of: upgrade to Vim 8, upgrade to a more recent version of vim-latex or downgrade to an earlier version should therefore fix your problem. I can't confirm version numbers but in my answer to the linked question I link to the relevant commits.

Comment: Thank you very much, in particular for the link.  I will (try to) upgrade vim to vim 8.0. Then, I hope, the problem will be fixed. Thanks again.

Comment: Excellent, please do let us know if it works or if not provide any extra information.

Comment: With vim 8 the plugin seems to work, now I have to learn how to really benefit from it, but that's another question. Thank you again for the help, the given link was great help.